Maintaining Palo Alto Security Policy with Terraform
I'm exploring Terraform for automated creation of Palo Alto firewall security rules using the panos_security_policy resource.
Having all security rules like this in the main.tf works as expected when adding / modifying / deleting the rules.
resource "panos_security_policy" "rules" {
    rule {
        name                  = "Rule-1"
        audit_comment         = "Initial config"
        source_zones          = [panos_zone.dmz.name]
        source_addresses      = [panos_panorama_address_group.addgrp1.name]
        source_users          = ["any"]
        destination_zones     = [panos_zone.internet.name]
        destination_addresses = ["any"]
        applications          = ["ssh"]
        services              = ["application-default"]
        categories            = ["any"]
        action                = "allow"
    }
    rule {
        name                  = "Rule-2"
        audit_comment         = "Initial config"
        source_zones          = [panos_zone.dmz.name]
        source_addresses      = [panos_panorama_address_group.addgrp1.name]
        source_users          = ["any"]
        destination_zones     = [panos_zone.internet.name]
        destination_addresses = ["any"]
        applications          = ["any"]
        services              = ["any"]
        categories            = ["any"]
        action                = "deny"
    }
  
    lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
    }
}

But I dont want to keep all details about the rules in the main.tf Especialy if the rulebase contains hundreds of rules. I want to keep them in the variables file. I've created something like this:
resource "panos_security_policy" "CreateSecurityRules" {
    for_each = var.securityRules

    rule {
      name                      = each.value.name
      source_zones              = each.value.source_zones
      source_addresses          = each.value.source_addresses
      source_users              = each.value.source_users
      destination_zones         = each.value.destination_zones
      destination_addresses     = each.value.destination_addresses
      applications              = each.value.applications
      services                  = each.value.services
      categories                = each.value.categories
      action                    = each.value.action
    }

    lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
    }
}

variable securityRules {
    type = map(object({
        name                    = string
        source_zones            = list(string)
        source_addresses        = list(string)
        source_users            = list(string)
        destination_zones       = list(string)
        destination_addresses   = list(string)
        applications            = list(string)
        services                = list(string)
        categories              = list(string)
        action                  = string
    }))
}

    rule1 = {
        name                    = "First rule"
        source_zones            = ["Inside"]
        source_addresses        = ["any"]
        source_users            = ["any"]
        destination_zones       = ["Outside"]
        destination_addresses   = ["any"]
        applications            = ["any"]
        services                = ["application-default"]
        categories              = ["any"]
        action                  = "allow"
    }
    rule2 = {
        name                    = "Second rule"
        source_zones            = ["Inside"]
        source_addresses        = ["any"]
        source_users            = ["any"]
        destination_zones       = ["DMZ"]
        destination_addresses   = ["any"]
        applications            = ["any"]
        services                = ["application-default"]
        categories              = ["any"]
        action                  = "allow"
    }
    rule3 = {
        name                    = "Third rule"
        source_zones            = ["DMZ"]
        source_addresses        = ["any"]
        source_users            = ["any"]
        destination_zones       = ["Outside"]
        destination_addresses   = ["any"]
        applications            = ["any"]
        services                = ["application-default"]
        categories              = ["any"]
        action                  = "allow"
    }
}

Unfortunately, I don't have any luck with this code. Initially, Terraform manages to create the rules on the firewall, but not in the right order - something which is very important. If I rerun Terraform again, the expectation is that no changes are needed, but it does make some - either delete some rules or assign null values.
I assume the issue is with the logic behind the map looping (p.s. I tried with lists as well, again with no success).
Could you please help me solve this problem?

Did my solution helped you?

Thank you for your response, but the solution here was to use "Dynamic Block":
resource "panos_security_policy" "CreateSecurityRules" {
dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = var.securityRules

    content {
        name                      = rule.value.name
        description               = rule.value.description
        audit_comment             = rule.value.audit_comment
        source_zones              = rule.value.source_zones
        source_addresses          = rule.value.source_addresses
        source_users              = rule.value.source_users
        destination_zones         = rule.value.destination_zones
        destination_addresses     = rule.value.destination_addresses
        applications              = rule.value.applications
        services                  = rule.value.services
        categories                = rule.value.categories
        group                     = rule.value.group
        action                    = rule.value.action
    }
}

lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
}

}

Yes of course you should use dynamic block to create the rules - I've used null_resource for demonstration purposes only. Given that the rule order matters, be careful with the names (aka map keys) you choose for your rules: rule-1, rule-2 and rule-10 will be sorted rule-1, rule-10 and rule-2. See my answer for more details.


Terraform manages to create the rules on the firewall, but not in the right order - something which is very important

According to panos_security_policy, the security rule ordering will match how they appear in the terraform plan file.
I did some quick tests using a variable of type map(object) and a null_resource - results will be displayed in the plan file sorted alphabetically by map key.
Consider the following module:
variable "securityRules" {
  type = map(object({
    name = string
  }))
}

resource "null_resource" "securityRules" {
  for_each = var.securityRules

  triggers = {
    name = each.value.name
  }
}

Running terraform plan with the following terraform.tfvars file:
securityRules = {
  "rule100" = {
    name = "xyz"
  }
  "rule2" = {
    name = "bar"
  }
  "rule1" = {
    name = "foo"
  }
}

Result is:
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.securityRules["rule1"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "securityRules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "name" = "foo"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.securityRules["rule100"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "securityRules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "name" = "xyz"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.securityRules["rule2"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "securityRules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "name" = "bar"
        }
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Ooops! Rules do get sorted by map key but not the way I expected (rule100 should be the last one).
Changing the keys slightly and running terraform plan:
securityRules = {
  "rule0100" = {
    name = "xyz"
  }
  "rule0002" = {
    name = "bar"
  }
  "rule0001" = {
    name = "foo"
  }
}

Result is the following:
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.securityRules["rule0001"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "securityRules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "name" = "foo"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.securityRules["rule0002"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "securityRules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "name" = "bar"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.securityRules["rule0100"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "securityRules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "name" = "xyz"
        }
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Results are now properly sorted.
Changing the order of the elements in the map:
securityRules = {
  "rule0002" = {
    name = "bar"
  }
  "rule0001" = {
    name = "foo"
  }
  "rule0100" = {
    name = "xyz"
  }
}

Result is the same as before:
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.securityRules["rule0001"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "securityRules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "name" = "foo"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.securityRules["rule0002"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "securityRules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "name" = "bar"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.securityRules["rule0100"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "securityRules" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "name" = "xyz"
        }
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

